# Volley attach access token to evey request using singleton

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am doing the following which perfectly works

```
    //else proceed with the checks
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            checkauthurl,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) { 
                         //do stuff here
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   // do stuff here
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String> ();
                    TokenService tokenservice = new TokenService(ctx);
                    String accesstoken = tokenservice.getToken(ApiHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_SHARED_PREF);
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

                    return headers;
              }
    };

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    ApiSingleton strngle = new ApiSingleton(ctx);
    strngle.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

For every request, I have to add the request header.  How can I set request headers directly in the singleton.

This is my singleton

```
private static ApiSingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
public static Context mCtx;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

public ApiSingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    //do stuff
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

How do I avoid the above code duplication when attaching the bearer token in every request?

Comment: You can use Request interceptor to capture the request and modify it before creating the actual request

Comment: Why don't you create a class, f.e. MyJsonObjectRequest, extending the JsonObjectRequest and override the class method getHeaders? Do you have any specific reason you want to do it in the singleton?

Comment: @ZachariasHadjikyprianou its not a must that they are added in a sigleton but am looking for a way to prevent code duplication in multiple areas

Comment: your singleton is not a singleton

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends JsonRequest<Object>{
    public CustomJsonRequest(String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<Object> listener,
                       Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public CustomJsonRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<Object> listener,
                       Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected Response<Object> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        return Response.success(Object, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String> ();
        TokenService tokenservice = new TokenService(ctx);
        String accesstoken = tokenservice.getToken(ApiHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_SHARED_PREF);
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);
        return headers;
    }
}
```

You can extend JsonRequest class and override getHeaders() method.
Pass instance of CustomJsonRequest object when you are adding volley requests in queue.

```
VolleyUtils.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(customJsonRequest);
```

Comment: Shouldn't he override `jsonObjectRequest` ?
Can `jsonRequest` be used for synchronous requests?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write a "Factory" with a method that takes your `checkauthurl` and `ctx` and returns you an instance of the JsonObjectRequest.  Your factory could implement some logic for re-use of objects that have the same auth Url if that makes sense in your case.
2. You can sub-class `JsonObjectRequest` and provide your `checkauthurl` and `ctx` as a parameter to the constructor.  Similarly, you can implement a scheme to re-use the objects

The factory would be the suggested approach if you want Dependency Injection.

I would recommend against pre-allocating the `Token` and using it in multiple requests. Tokens expire.  If the TokenService is written well, it should know when tokens will expire and refresh as needed (if possible).

Answer (score -2):

Make an AppController.java file and mention this file name as android:app in manifest tag.

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Do the networking code

```
 StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_BUYER_LOGIN, 
new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                }
            };
            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }
```

Comment: where are the request headers added in your solution. Am looking for away to reduce code duplication when attaching the bearer request header

Comment: What you are doing now is creating AliSingleton class object again and again an calling method to attach request header.

What I did is created a application level class in which therr is method to attach request header. You simply have to call method to attach request header and name that class in manifest as android:app tag.